# Fetch the function return value in PHP extension C++

Tags: php, php-extension, php-internals

I have created an php extension in c++ which tracks the call graph of each request(centos7-64 bit,PHP5.6).And now,I want to get the function **return value** of each function.
It can be done by using zend_excute_data structure(original_return_value).

```
 zend_execute_data *data;
 data = EG(current_execute_data);
 if(data->original_return_value)
 {
        zval *rvalue = *(data->original_return_value);    // crashing here
    switch (Z_TYPE(argument_element))
        {
        ..
        .. 
        ..
    }
 }
```

Here, while assigning the original_return_value to rvalue,my php extension getting crash.
Is this correct way to do? or anything else.

Comment: I tried with EG(return_value_ptr_ptr) global also,still i didn't get.

Answer (score 0):

```
zval *rvalue = *(data->original_return_value);    // crashing here
```

Its because of the last deref of `original_return_value`.
Either the data object or original_return_value is uninitialized or corrupted memory.

Comment: The data object has the value.May be original_return_value points the corrupted memory. Other than this,how can i get the function return value?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.

```
zval **return_value_ptr = &EX_TMP_VAR(execute_data, execute_data->opline->result.var)->var.ptr;
```

return_value_ptr is has the return value of currently executed function.